# Route parameters with a new path

Tags: reactjs, compiler-errors

`

1. I am trying to update the app to have /, /user/:userId, and /user/new routes and any
   other route displays a 404 message.
2. I got Error please help. Error:
   Expected substring: "Unable to create a new user"
   Received string: "<div class="App"><a href="/">Home<a
   href="/user/new">New User<a data-testid="user-1"
   href="/user/1">User1<a ..."`

```
//App.js
import React from "react";
import "./style.css";
import { Link, Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";
import NoMatch from "./NoMatch";
import UserProfile from "./UserProfile";

function Home() {
  return <h1>Home</h1>;
}

function NewUser(){
  return <h1>Unable to create a new user</h1>;
}

function App() {
  return (
    // No need to add <Router>, it has been added to ./index.js
    <div className="App">
      <div>
        <Link to="/">Home</Link>
      </div>
      <div>
        <Link to="/user/new">New User</Link>
      </div>
      
      {Array(10)
        .fill()
        .map((ignoredValue, index) => index + 1)
        .map((id) => (
          <div key={id}>
            <Link to={`/user/${id}`} data-testid={`user-${id}`}>
              User{id}
            </Link>
          </div>
        ))}
      // Setup routes with route paramaters as needed
      <Switch>
        <Route exact={true} path="/">
          <Home />
        </Route>
        <Route path="/user/:userId">
          <UserProfile />
        </Route>
        <Route path="/user/new">
          <NewUser />
        </Route>
        <Route>
          <NoMatch />
        </Route>
      </Switch>

    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`Link` components are used after the route they need to access has been defined prior in router context (in someplace higher up the component hierarchy).
Hence I think you may have to define your routes setup in the parent component of `<App />` because the routing context cannot not be correctly inferred else.

Comment: Router has been added to index.js.

Comment: @HajerThabet I understand that the Router has been already declared in the index.js file. What I meant is that you have to move your Switch and Route components also from ```<App />``` to its parent which i am guessing is the index.js file

Comment: I found the solution. I have to put <Route path="/user/new"> before <Route path="/user/:userId">. Thank you for help.

Comment: @hajerthabet happy to hear that you solved it out. I guess it would be best if you probably post what worked out as a seperate answer under this thread and mark it as the accepted so that it might help  someone else who might also come across this same problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think the error is coming from *Array(10).fill()* expression. Can you try it again by modifying this expression? To me *Array(10).fill()* returning *undefined*. If you want to generate an Array that has elements 1 up to 10, use the following snippet instead.

```
[...Array(10).keys()] 
//=> [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

OR

```
Array.from(Array(10).keys())
//=> [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Comment: I tried your solution. Unfortunately, it didn't work.